# QuickBooks user information

Tags: quickbooks

I am doing custom development in QuickBooks and want to retrieve user information.

I have used 'AccessBooks RealTime' to export the schema as well as data to SQL Server. I have explored complete database but could not find any table, that is being used to save user information.

Alternatively, is there any API that will return user information?

Answer (score 1):

None of the QuickBooks APIs supports grabbing user information from QuickBooks. Thus, regardless of what technique you use, you can't get at that data.